# Algebra inequation proof

Tags: calculus

$$ \epsilon > 0 \\ x,y,a,b \in \mathbb{R}  \\ |y-b|< \epsilon  \\ |x-a|< \epsilon $$  We need to prove the next inequality;

$$ |xy-ab| < \epsilon (|a|+|b|+\epsilon) $$

And I'm trying, but no success. There's a hint: $$ xy-ab=xy-ab+xb-xb$$

Anyone?

Comment: Write $y=b±\epsilon$, $x=a\pm\epsilon$ and expand. Or, mathematically more correct, $y=b+\epsilon_1$, $x=a+\epsilon_2$, where $|\epsilon_{1,2}|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $y=b+\epsilon_1$, $x=a+\epsilon_2$, where $|\epsilon_{1,2}|<\epsilon$. Now you have

$$|xy-ab|=|a\epsilon_1+b\epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2|$$
Now use triangle inequality on the right hand side, and then use the inequality of the epsilons in the sense $\epsilon_1\epsilon_2<\epsilon^2$ and $|a\epsilon_1|< |a|\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice following the hint:

$$ |xy-ab| \leq |x||y-b| + |b||x-a| = |x-a+a||y-b| + |b||x-a| \leq |x-a||y-b| + |a||y-b| + |b||x-a| < \epsilon^2 + |a| \epsilon + |b| \epsilon = \epsilon( \epsilon  + |a| + |b| )$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $x-a=u$ and $y-b=v$; then $|u|<\varepsilon$ and $|v|<\varepsilon$. Since $xy=(u+a)(v+b)=uv+av+bu+ab$, we have
$$
|xy-ab|=|uv+av+bu|\le |u|\,|v|+|a|\,|v|+|b|\,|u|<\dots
$$